# Passing text to compiled CSS without using comments

Tags: sass

Is there any way to pass custom text to compiled CSS? We're trying to pass {if} statements but don't want to have comments tag in final CSS:

```css
{if something}
body { color: red; }
{/if}
```

Now I've got compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) `#{}` and quotes `' '`:

```
#{'{if something}'}
body { color: red; }
#{'{/if}'}
```